# Can I convert a list of embedded links in MS Word back to text at one time - there are 100 of them?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, hyperlink, embedded

**Problem** Not all the embedded hyperlinks in my 2016 MS Word document work in the references section when converted to PDF. They are listed as titles with embedded links.

**What I've done** Well, apparently, as of April 2021, I found a post this is a "known issue" at Microsoft. I have over 100 linked references. All the embedded and bookmarked links work up to a point then stop for the remainder of the document. I tried using the ALT+F9 which converts them for viewing but can't be copied and replaced as links.

Is there a way to select and convert those back to links without selecting them all individually?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this was possible after further digging:

1. Press Alt + F9 to display the fields
2. Ctrl + F to open the search box
3. Search: ^d hyperlink
4. Check "Highlight all items found ..."
5. Click on the Find All button
6. Close the dialog
7. Ctrl + C to copy everything that is highlighted
8. Open a new document and paste.

https://ccm.net/faq/25198-word-extract-all-hyperlinks-from-a-document

Comment: This is a link-only answer, but links can disappear. Your answer should contain enough information to stand up by itself.